# Why does VIM paste 1 line below where expected?

Tags: vim, vi

A simple recipe to demonstrate the behavior of pasting in Vim/Vi...

1. Run vim
2. Enter insert mode
3. Add 3 different lines of garbage to your file
4. Exit insert mode (press escape)
5. Move the caret to the second line
6. Enter the command `dd` (delete line)
7. Enter the command `p` (paste)

Notice the pasted line is inserted below where you might expect it to be placed.

Why is Vim/Vi programmed with this behavior, and is there any way to change it? (ie: Have the line pasted one line above the default position.)

Comment: maybe give someone the checkmark on this one...

Answer (score 17):

Use `P`. It will paste above the cursor instead of below.

Comment: The help for this is in ``:help paste``, ``:help p``

Answer (score 2):

`p` will paste below the current line, `P` will paste above the line. If you want you can swap the behaviors of `P` and `p` add the following to your vimrc.

```
nnoremap p P
nnoremap P p
```

Comment: A helpful hint, thanks - I'll remap it to something else like [ (which is next to p) rather than p itself which might be confusing